# How I can remove job from redis queue by job id?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, queue

I found how to get the job id after creating it, but how I can remove this job from queue?

```
$chat = \App\Models\Chat\Chat::first();
    $chatUser = App\Models\Chat\ChatUser::first();
    $virtualId = 'asd';

    $job = (new \App\Jobs\Chat\CloseClientChat(
        $chat,
        $chatUser,
        $virtualId
    ))
        ->onConnection('redis')
        ->onQueue('chat')
        ->delay(now()->addSeconds(15));

    $jobId  = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher::class)->dispatch($job);

/** how to remove from \Queue ? **/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `delete` or `release` the underlying queue job. Import the `Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue` trait to get access to these methods if you are trying to do this in a class outside of the listener.  It's loaded by default on the listener, so those methods are available already there.

Laravel's docs give an example of how to do this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#queued-event-listeners).  Look for "Manually Accessing The Queue'"

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to delete the pending job before processing it in the handle method.